# When should I collect SharedFlow events in Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I thought that it is okay to collect `SharedFlow` data in `onViewCreated`. But when I replace fragment n times then I fire some event to `SharedFlow`, it emits n times event to me instead of one event.

To fix it I put my code in `onCreate` of my fragment. I couldn't find any documentation about that. Am I missing something or should I keep collecting `SharedFlow` in `onCreate` in the fragment?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        viewModel.uiEffect.collect {
            when (it) {
                is ViewEffectWrapper.PageEffect -> {
                    if (it.pageEvent is LoginViewEffect.OpenHomePage) {
                        startActivity(
                            Intent(
                                this@LoginFragment.context,
                                HomeActivity::class.java
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `SharedFlow` definition in the `ViewModel`

```
private val _uiEffect = MutableSharedFlow<ViewEffectWrapper<LoginViewEffect>>(replay = 0)
val uiEffect: SharedFlow<ViewEffectWrapper<LoginViewEffect>> = _uiEffect
```

Answer (score 16):

You are not currently using the `viewLifecycleOwner` and it is recommended to use that for `Fragments` as that is tied to the Fragment Views Lifecycle. This is the recommended way to do it

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.uiEffect.collect {
                    // do stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would also like to give this a read. It is a good read and worth to help you ahead.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Comment: Thanks it works and i am reading story right now thank you so much.

Comment: is it any difference if I use lifeCycle.launch ?